# How should connection string look like in web.config if you want to connect to SQLServerExpress with instance name mssqlserver2 in ASP.NET 4.5?

Tags: asp.net, connection-string, sql-server-express

I have a named instance of SQLServerExpress of mssqlserver2

And with the computer name first:

```
w7\mssqlserver2
```

But how should the connection string look like in web.config if you want to connect to SQLExpress to that server?

This is for the logincontrols so it can create those tables.

```
<!-- Not working connstring -->
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Site-20130227161535;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

Error mess>

Server Error in '/' Application.

*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.*

Comment: It's hard to know how your system is setup or how you installed the database. I use visual studio Server explorer to verify connection string. Try creating a datasource and compare the generated connection string e.g. when using SQLDataSource control

Comment: Ok thanks but can you explain in more detail how you go about creating datasource. You dont mean connect to database? Because the SQLServerExpress is in Server Explorer. Shouldn't the generated string be correct in web.config then? Or when I renamed the instance to mssqlserver2 it didn't get that right? If I get you right a default installation of SQLServerExpress is ". .\SQLEXPRESS;..." in the connection string and that is autogenerated in web.config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=w7\mssqlserver2;Initial Catalog=YOUR_DATABASE;Integrated Security=SSPI" />
```

Comment: Ok great thanks! Gonna check this one. But how should you understand these connectionstrings?  1) The . in .\ does it stand for localhost? And 2) Initial Catalog is that referring to a table in the database? And 3) Integrated Security=SSPI what could you have more with this security?

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Initial Catalog : database connected to firstly. 3) Don't know.